# Why these commands fail if I concatenate them (with "|")?

Tags: regex, vim

To turn this:

```
·     阿富汗 Country1

·     阿爾及利亞 Country2

·     孟加拉 Country3 

＊  ·  不丹 Country4 (請參閱下列＊說明處)
```

into this:

```
Country1,Country2,Country3,Country4
```

I do the following:

```
%s/[^\x00-\x7F]//g
```

Remove the Chinese characters.

```
%s/\s\+$//g
```

Remove the trailing white spaces

```
%s/\s\+//g
```

Remove remaining whites paces

```
g/^$/d
```

Remove empty lines

```
%s/\n/,/g
```

Connected each line into a single one (each word separated by a comma).

Now I want to do that in one command. So I concatenated all those commands:

```
%s/[^\x00-\x7F]//g|%s/\s\+$//g|%s/\s\+//g|g/^$/d|%s/\n/,/g
```

Which produces this:

```
Country1,Country2,,Country3,,Country4,
```

I find it strange since the commands work if I use them separately.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not all Ex command can be concatenated. Some commands, like the `:global` command, can themselves take a sequence of commands, and therefore eat up all remaining arguments, including the `|` command separator. See `:help :bar` for a list of such commands. The help also provides a solution if you do want to include such a command in a sequence: You need to enclose the command itself with `:execute`. Applied to your problem, this becomes:

```
%s/[^\x00-\x7F]//g|%s/\s\+$//g|%s/\s\+//g|exe 'g/^$/d'|%s/\n/,/g
```

With this, the last `:s` command is applied to the entire buffer, and not within the scope of the `:global` command.

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
%s/[^\x00-\x7F]\|\s//g|%s/\n\{2,}/,/g
```